# Начало работы с MQ java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms

Есть сервер, который реализует в себе MQ 
Пытаюсь подключиться к нему, используя jms, но видимо что-то в настройке упустил.
Выдает ошибку:

*

```
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: Стандартная библиотека JNI 'mqjbnd64' не найдена. Для установки в системе клиента - предполагается. [3=mqjbnd64]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd64 in java.library.path
```

*

Не могу найти решение этой по всей видимости простой проблемы
Неужели в сети нет мануалов по настройке и подключению с нуля?

Comment: Почему у вас в тегах RabbitMQ, если вы пытаетесь подключаться к IBM MQ, судя по ошибке?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to establish a bindings connection to a local queue manager,
>   you must have installed MQ on the machine where the java or JMS
>   application is running. If MQ is not installed locally, or if the
>   target queue manager is on a different system, you must use a client
>   connection instead.

[IBM Support](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248900)